# Symfony user login link in chain user providers

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating PasswordLess api for my symfony project by following this: https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/login_link.html

I have multiple firewalls:

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:                        ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security:                       false

        install:
            pattern:                        ^/installer
            security:                       false
            anonymous:                      true

        login:
            pattern:                        ^/user/(login|reset-request|send-email|check-email|auto-login)$
            provider:                       chain_provider
            anonymous:                      true
            #login_link:                    # ERROR HERE
            #    check_route: login_check
            #    signature_properties: ['id']

        main:
            pattern:                        ^/
            provider:                       chain_provider
            form_login:
                csrf_token_generator:       security.csrf.token_manager
                check_path:                 main_security_check
                login_path:                 main_security_login
                use_forward:                true
            logout:
                path:                       main_security_logout
            remember_me:
                secret:                     "%env(APP_SECRET)%"
                name:                       BAPRM
                lifetime:                   1209600   # stay logged for two weeks
                samesite:                   'lax'
            anonymous:                      false
```

But when I try to configure it I get this error:

```
The old authentication system is not supported with login_link.
```

How can I make it work, what I am missing here.

I am using `Symfony 5.4`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/login_link.html) you have to enable the new authenticator system to use login links.

> Login links are only supported by Symfony when using the authenticator system. Before using this authenticator, make sure you have enabled it with enable_authenticator_manager: true in your security.yaml file.

So modify your `security.yaml` to add:

`enable_authenticator_manager: true`

If you do not use it, for example if you use [guards](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-guard-component-deprecation), you will have to replace it with the [new system](https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/experimental_authenticators.html).